# how to use async/await to allow my props to be read after state is updated (react.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-props

I am trying to to pass down props to a react child component with information from an API, and I know the API information and all the syntax is correct because, if I don't refresh the page, all the information is there. But as soon as I Do, an error is thrown saying it "can't read property '...' undefined"

This is the parent Component:

```
function TeamList() {
    const [URL, setURL] = useState('http://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/86/')
    const [team, setTeam] = useState([])
    const [teamName, setTeamName] = useState('Manchester United')
    async function getTeam() {
        setURL('http://api.football-data.org/v2/teams/86/')


        try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${URL}`, {
            headers: {
                'X-Auth-Token': '#'
            }
        })
        setTeamName(response.data.name)
        setTeam(response.data)

        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }


        useEffect(async() => {
            getTeam()
        }, [])

    return (
        <div className="Team">
            <h4> {teamName} </h4>
            <Team 
                activeComps = {team.activeCompetitions}
                address = {team.address}
                crest = {team.crestUrl}
                email = {team.email}
                founded = {team.founded}
                teamID = {team.id}
                tla = {team.tla}
                venue = {team.venue}
                website = {team.website}
                squad = {team.squad}
            />
        </div>
    )   
}

export default TeamList
```

This is the Child Component:

```
function Team(props) {
    return (
        <div className="Team" id={props.teamID}>
            <img src={props.crest} />
            <h5>Founded: {props.founded}</h5>
            <h5>Current Competitions</h5>
                <ul>
                    <li> <Link to ="/league">{props.activeComps[0].name}</Link></li>
                    <li> <Link to ="/league">{props.activeComps[1].name}</Link></li>
                </ul>
            <h5>Team Address: </h5>
            <p>{props.address}</p>
            <h5>Venue: </h5>
            <p>{props.venue}</p>
            <h5>Website: </h5>
            <p>{props.website}</p>
      
        </div>
    )
}

export default Team
```

Comment: Can you specify what property is throwing this error? Might be ```name``` of activeComps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue is that you're defaulting `team` to an empty array, but it seems to be an object when it's returned from the API call. To simplify things, we can just default it to `undefined`.

```js
const [team, setTeam] = useState();
```

The second issue, which is causing the errors you're hitting, is that you're trying to render the `Team` component before you have your data. To prevent this from happening, you can use a ternary operator to show a loading status while you're `team` is undefined (note that this recommendation only really works if you take my previous recommendation):

```
{team ? <Team 
  activeComps = {team.activeCompetitions}
  address = {team.address}
  crest = {team.crestUrl}
  email = {team.email}
  founded = {team.founded}
  teamID = {team.id}
  tla = {team.tla}
  venue = {team.venue}
  website = {team.website}
  squad = {team.squad}
/> : "Loading..."}
```

Also, I would probably recommend just passing the whole `team` object down to the `Team` component; that would really simplify the interface.